# Prove the set $S_{\mu}$ is convex

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Given the set $S_{\mu}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:||x-a||\leq\mu||x-b||\}$ prove for which $\mu$ $S_{\mu}$ is convex $(a\neq b)$.
I'm not sure if my way was good.
let $x,y\in S_{\mu}$ and $0\leq\lambda\leq1$.
$||\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y-a||=||\lambda(x-a)+(1-\lambda)(y-a)||\leq \lambda||x-a||+(1-\lambda)||y-a||\leq\mu(\lambda||x-b||+(1-\lambda)||y-b||)$.
and this is only possible if $\mu>0$.

Comment: How does this prove convexity? You need to show $\|\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y-a\|\le\mu\|\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y-b\|$. If $\mu<0,S_\mu$ is empty and hence convex. If $\mu=0,S_\mu=\{a\}$ so still $S_\mu$ is convex.

Comment: but $a\neq b$ so any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A warm thank to Shubham Johri who has pointed a big error of mine.

Two parts 1) and 2):

1. **Where your argumentation is flawed.**

You have to prove that

$$x,y\in S_{\mu} \implies \forall \lambda \in [0,1], x,y\in S_{\mu}$$

$$\iff \ \|\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y-a\|\le\mu\|\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y-b\| \tag{0}$$

What you do is to write the LHS of (0) in this way:

$$||\lambda(x-a)+(1-\lambda)(y-a)||$$

and then use majorations:

$$\leq \lambda||x-a||+(1-\lambda)||y-a||\leq\mu(\lambda||x-b||+(1-\lambda)||y-b||)$$

(nothing false ; **but** under the condition that $\mu>1$ !?).

But now, you are in the **wrong position** to apply triangle inequality and get the majoration of the RHS of (0).

2. **A proof.**

A first remark is that $\mu<0$ corresponds visibly to an impossible case when you see the definition, whereas the locus is surely nonvoid when $\mu \ge 0$ because considering points $x$ close enough to $a$ warrants the inequality.

Result: the convexity occurs for $0 \le \mu \le 1$.

We are going to prove explicitly that the locus is

- a **ball** if $0<\mu<1$,
- a **point** is $\mu=0$,
- a **hyperplane** is $\mu=1$.

Here is why. Let us start from :

$$x \in S_{\mu} \ \iff \ ||x-a||^2\leq\mu^2||x-b||^2 \tag{1}$$

Let us treat the case $n=2$, for the sake of simplicity (the general case is straightforward). (1) can be written with evident notations:

$$(x-a_1)^2+(y-a_2)^2\le \mu^2((x-b_1)^2+(y-b_2)^2)$$

$$(x^2+y^2)(1-\mu^2)-2(a_1-\mu^2b_1)x-2(a_2-\mu^2b_2)y+(a_1^2-\mu^2b_1^2+a_2^2-\mu^2b_2^2) \leq 0\tag{1}$$

Consider now 3 cases.

- If $0 \leq \mu \leq 1$, dividing (1) by $1-\mu^2>0$ gives an inequation of the form:

$$x^2+y^2-2x_cx-2y_cy+k \le 0$$

which is the **interior** of a disk with center $(x_c,y_c)$. Therefore, we have a convex set.

- If $\mu > 1$, dividing (1) by $1-\mu^2>0$ gives an inequation of the form (take care to the reversal of the inequality sign):

$$x^2+y^2-2x_cx-2y_cy+k \ge 0$$

which is the **exterior** of a disk with center $(x_c,y_c)$. Therefore, we do not have a convex set.

- if $\mu=1$**: the first term in (1) is cancelled, yielding a first degree equation, which is in a natural manner the **perpendicular bissector** of line segment $[a,b]$, a convex set.

Remark: the center of the disk is given by:

$$x_c=\dfrac{a_1-\mu^2b_1}{1-\mu^2}, \ \ y_c=\dfrac{b_1-\mu^2b_2}{1-\mu^2}$$

naturally situated on line segment $[a,b]$ (interior of a so-called "apollonian circle").

---

Here is a little graphical aid for the case $a=(0,0),b=(6,0),0\le\mu\le3$ (realized by
@Shubham Johri):

[image: Graph]

Comment: Wouldn't it be the exterior of a disk when $\mu>1$?

Comment: @Shubham Johri It is not possible because in this case it wouldn't be convex...

Comment: The given set is not convex for all $\mu$. I think the question is about finding those values of $\mu$ for which the set is convex. So we need to state that $\mu\le1$, no?

Comment: No, let us take the case $\mu=2$. Let us take $a=(0,0)$ and $b=(6,0)$. The locus is the closed disk with center $C=(-3,0)$ and radius $3$.

Comment: The locus of the **boundary** of the region is a circle but whether the feasible region is the interior or exterior of the circle is decided by the sign of $1-\mu^2$. I have [graphed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGwD6.png) the feasible region for your example and it is indeed non-convex.

Comment: hey @JeanMarie can you join the chat?
https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115523/prove-the-set-s-is-convex

Comment: @Shubham Johri You are perfectly right! Sorry for having so persistent in the error. A warm thank.

Comment: Can you say if this presentation such as I have corrected is now convenient for you ?

Comment: @Shubham Johri  Could you place your nice graphics as a (partial )answer ? I would be happy to upvote it. I think it would be of some help to people who do not know that one can easily manipulate inequations with Desmos.

Comment: Ok I will do it

Comment: Jean, I made a little animation [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htJl5.gif) for the case $a=(0,0),b=(6,0),0\le m\le3$. I would be more than happy to edit it into your answer if you are okay. Or you can edit it with the link.

Comment: @Shubham Johri. Thanks. Yes, edit it in my answer.

Comment: @Shubham Johri Thanks again. I appreciate very much. Have you seen this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius ?

Comment: @JeanMarie No, I haven't. I will go through it, looks interesting. Any specific section of interest?

Comment: @Shubham Johri In fact, this one is more precise: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonian_circles. One of the interests of this article is to show that to the first family (associated with distances' ratios) a dual family exists of (orthogonal) circles, this one associated to a preservation of angles. What is not said is that there exists a very nice complex function interpretation: take $Z=f(z)=\tfrac{z-1}{z+1}$. Then $\{z| \Re(Z)=\mu\}$ is the first family of circles and  $\{z| \Im(Z)=\nu\}$ is the second one, naturally orthogonal due to the fact that f is differentiable (holomorphic).